# JSF website and redirecting pages

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a website that was written using JSF 1.2.
I've been made aware that on one of our pages, you click a button and and http redirect is supposed to occur. This is not working.

My JSF file contains the button:

```
<h:commandButton immediate="true"
                 action="#{jLoginFragment.btnLogin_onClick}" 
                 id="btnLogin"
                 value="Login"
                 styleClass="buttonComp"/>
```

My bean contains:

```
public String btnLogin_onClick() {
    System.out.println ('TEST');
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/test.html");
    return null;
}
```

When I click on the button, the `btnLogin_onClick()` is executed (as I can see the 'TEST' message, but the redirect does not happen.

No exceptions are thrown, so I'm a little stuck on what to do here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Create an mcve please

Comment: Can you tell me what is MCVE?

Comment: The link behind 1st hit on Google.

Comment: Please elaborate "does not work" in developer's terms instead of enduser's terms. Is the HTTP request fired? Is the FacesServlet hit? Is the action event queued? Is the invoke application phase entered? Is the action method hit? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the Google Tag Manager code we have on our site is causing the redirect not to work. I've removed the tag manager code for this particular page.